# MVC Ajax forms not submitting on page load with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am having a problem getting a form to post on load. The code to do the loading is simply:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#resultsForm').triggerHandler('submit');
}
```

and for the markup, I am simply using an MVC Ajax form:

```
    <% using (Ajax.BeginForm("resultsForm", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "resultsDiv", OnSuccess = "onSuccess" })) { %> 
//html in here  
    <% } %>
```

In FF and Chrome, the page loads, and then a couple seconds later the div for the results loads as well. This is what I expect to happen. However, in IE nothing happens.

When I try to do

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#resultsForm').trigger('submit');
}
```

The page loads in IE, and then redirects me to a page that is just the results for the form.

Any ideas on how to get around this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some looking around, I came across a solution for my problem. The solution can be found [here](http://paululvinius.wordpress.com/2009/03/03/how-you-dynamically-submit-a-aspnet-mvc-ajax-form-), and using my example it would look like:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var form = $('#resultsForm');
    form.submit(function(event) { eval($(this).attr("onsubmit")); return false; });
    form.submit();
}
```

This worked for me in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really familiar with MVC Ajax, but normally you would put the submit code for the form into a function and call that instead.
ie.

```
function doThisOnSubmit() {
   //Submit code here
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    doThisOnSubmit();
});
```

And then your HTML code:

```
<form onsubmit="doThisOnSubmit();">
<!-- Stuff -->
</form>
```

Hopefully this helps.